# PMD Apex Can't find resource for rule on Windows

Tags: code-analysis, apex, pmd, static-code-analysis

I'm trying to configure PMD for code analysis.
I'm using VS Code, already installed Java 10, downloaded several versions of PMD [image]

I've installed the Apex PMD extension for VS Code and configured it as per it's instructions.

But keep getting the can't find resource error no matter which version I choose.

This is part of the output from VS Code

> PMD Command: java -cp "C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib*" net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD -d "c:\Code\Lightning\src\classes\AccountController.cls" -f csv -R "C:\Code\ruleset\apex_default.xml"
>   error:Error: Command failed: java -cp "C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib*" net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD -d "c:\Code\Lightning\src\classes\AccountController.cls" -f csv -R "C:\Code\ruleset\apex_default.xml"
>   Sep 12, 2018 2:35:20 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RulesetsFactoryUtils getRuleSets
>   SEVERE: Ruleset not found
>   net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'category/apex/design.xml' for rule 'ExcessiveParameterList'.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Here's the current classpath: C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\antlr4-runtime-4.5.2-1.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\groovy-2.4.7.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\gson-2.5.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\javacc-5.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\jaxen-1.1.6.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-apex-5.7.0-apex-jorje-shaded.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-apex-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-core-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-cpp-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-cs-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-fortran-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-go-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-groovy-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-java-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-javascript-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-jsp-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-matlab-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-objectivec-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-perl-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-php-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-plsql-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-python-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-ruby-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-scala-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-swift-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-ui-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-visualforce-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-vm-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\pmd-xml-5.7.0.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\rhino-1.7.7.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\saxon-9.1.0.8-dom.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\saxon-9.1.0.8.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\scala-library-2.10.4.jar;C:\Code\pmd-bin-5.7.0\lib\scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar

If i run the command from command line I get a similar output.
This error is for every rule I have on my ruleset which is nothing out of the ordinary, it's the default ruleset that comes with the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with PMD 6.7.0 and fails with 5.7.0:

The rule, you reference "category/apex/design.xml/ExcessiveParameterList" is available under this path only since PMD 6. With that version, we put the rules into categories.
When using PMD 5.7.0, you'll need to use the old ruleset: "rulesets/apex/complexity.xml/ExcessiveParameterList".
It's probably better to use the latest PMD version. Is there a way, to configure the Apex PMD extension?

See also https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1344